# Export data from one database to another WITHOUT x fields?

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I would like to move data from one table (*table1*) to another (*table2*). They have almost the same fields but table1 has some extra fields (with data) that I don't need in table2.

So i can't just do a CSV export & import because I end up with erros. So my question; how do I create an export of a database field without field X, Y and Z?

**edit**:

Lets say I have a table1 with the following fields;

```
id, name, comment, email, date
```

And with table2 I have;

```
id, name, comment, date
```

So no `email` field. If I make a CSV export of table1  I can't directly import it into table2 because there is an extra field (email).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table2 SELECT field1, field2, etc FROM table1
```

If `table2` already exists then:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT field1, field2, etc FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

While inserting just select the fields you want to insert

```
insert into table2 (id, name, comment, date)
    select id, name, comment, date
    from table1
```

Comment: I'm sorry. What do you mean? Which fields? Do you want to delete all data in table2 before?

Comment: I updated my answer. Select only the fields from `table1` that you want to insert in `table2`

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting data using sql server management studio, then there is an option to 
give the query instead of selecting the table for export.

So give your reuired fields in the query

```
SSMS ->
right click on database->Tasks->export data -> 

after selecting the source and destination, you get a window called
"Specify table copy or Query"
```

there you can select the second option and provide query